# Jquery show and hide using checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a dynamically generated table, and in one column I have a checkbox field and a text field. What I'm trying to achieve is if the checkbox is checked it will show the text field. And if its unchecked it will hide the text field. The jquery code below works, but I need to change the second function to not only hide once unchecked, but also show once checked again.

```
<div id="nfl" class="grid-view">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <tr data-key="9">
            <td>3</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="" value="Green Bay"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="" value="Cincinnati"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="" value="3" maxlength="3" style="width:40px"></td>
            <td><select name="">
                    <option value="favorite" selected="">favorite</option>
                    <option value="underdog">underdog</option>
                </select></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="checked" name="" value="1" checked=""> <input type="text" name="" value="33" maxlength="3" style="width:50px"></td><td><a class="deleteLink" href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td></tr>
        <tr data-key="10">
            <td>4</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="" value="Jacksonville"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="" value="Buffalo"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="" value="4" maxlength="3" style="width:40px"></td>
            <td><select name="">
                    <option value="favorite">favorite</option>
                    <option value="underdog" selected="">underdog</option>
                </select></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="checked" name="" value="1" checked=""> <input type="text" name="" value="54" maxlength="3" style="width:50px"></td><td><a class="deleteLink" href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nfl .deleteLink").on("click",function() {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        tr.css("background-color","#FF3700");

        tr.fadeOut(400, function(){
            tr.remove();
        });
      return false;
    });
    $("#nfl .checked").on("change",function() {
        var td = $(this).closest('td');
        var total = $(this).siblings(":text");
        total.fadeOut(400, function(){
            total.hide();
        });
      return false;
    });        
});
```

Comment: Yes i tried the  if statement along with the checked selector but could not get any of it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add class `c-box` to the checkbox.

```
<input type="checked checkbox" class="c-box" name="" value="1" checked="">
```

Then try using `fadeToggle`

```
$('.c-box').change(function () {                
    var td = $(this).closest('td');
    var total = $(this).siblings(":text");
    total.fadeToggle("slow", "linear" );
    return false;
});
```

You can customize the [fadeToggle](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) function as you prefer

Answer (score 0):

put this statement in your function that triggers on `checked` property of `#nfl` change: `if(('#nfl').is(':checked'))` and act accordingly to the result : )